# text cuts off when trying to print the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having an issue with Print Preview, the text which is inside a div cuts off when its too long.

I have made a sample on this link where you can also experience the same problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lemy1qrp/11/

When you try to print it for some reason full text is not showing up in second page.

I would love to know from you how can I fix this.

If you try to run this locally save the file as .html and open in any browser it works fine but for some reason on the link above it doesnt as well as when i integrate that piece of html code on my web app.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-container > div {
 background:silver;

}
@media print {

}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd
  1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd
  1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksdjk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ak1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksdjk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ak1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksdjk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ak1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksdjk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ak1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksdjk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ad ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksdjk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk  jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk1ajksd ajksd ajksd jk the end</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am also attaching a screenshot so u can see the problem.
[image]

As you can see on the image text doesnt continue on the second page but it cuts off.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside

Comment: can you please be more specific @CarolMcKay, what should I change on my example?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add paragraphs and or list items, other elements in you div, not just the text dump into a div:

```
.flex-container > div {
 break-inside: auto;
}

.flex-container > div ol, 
.flex-container > div ul, 
.flex-container > div p {
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Comment: did u try the demo? is it working for you? it doesnt work for me this!

Comment: I added a statement to the answer that I had meant to say.

Comment: also why is it working without wrapping into a paragraph or list items when I run same example locally, for ex i store the code as a file .html and open it print preview works all fine, I can see whole text into two pages within print preview!